# Filling missing date values with the least possible date in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date column as,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2014-10-01', np.nan, '2015-09-30', np.nan, np.nan, '2019-06-03']})
```

Now I want to impute the missing date values with the least possible date value in pandas. Imputing the current date is easy `datetime.now()` but for one particular case I want the `NaN` values to be imputed with the least possible value in dates.

Now **`datetime`** allows minimum date to be as **`'0001-01-01'`** but the same is not acceptable with pandas. Upon imputing this value the error I get is

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

I tried looking up on stackoverflow but couldn't find a possible answer to minimum acceptable date in pandas.

Is anyone aware of this?

EDIT: I'm not really concerned with 'OutOfBondsDatetime', I'm curios to know the least possible date that pandas can accept.

Comment: The least possible valid date with a zero time component would be `pd.Timestamp.min.ceil('D')`. You will need to fill NaNs with this if you want to be able to convert this to a datetime column.

Comment: try this:
    
    df.fillna(pd.Timestamp.min.date())

Comment: @AmanSingh I can't imagine KallolSamanta's solution working for you because you'd _still_ get `OutOfBoundsDatetime` when converting to datetime.

Comment: @cs95 You're absolutely right, I just tried doing the conversion to datetime and I got that same error. Guess you are right even the nano seconds could cause the trouble.

Comment: Thanks @cs95 taking the ceil of minimum timestamp did the trick

Comment: OK, reopening this because the solution is a little more nuanced than the current duplicate.

Comment: @cs95 sure, you can actually close the other one as dupe if you want after posting an answer. I am sure it will cover the other answer too. :)

Comment: @anky_91 While the dupe was a bit off this time, I really appreciate the effort to close questions rather than answering them. We need less dupe answering and more dupe closing in this tag. (PS: cannot mark that as a dupe of this yet since this question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer.... yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a date that plays nicely with pandas, you'll need to consider `pd.Timestamp`, since this is the `datetime` type that pandas works with.

If you don't mind your dates having a time component, use `pd.Timestamp.min`:

```
pd.Timestamp.min
# Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

pd.to_datetime(df['date'].fillna(pd.Timestamp.min))

0   2014-10-01 00:00:00.000000
1   1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225
2   2015-09-30 00:00:00.000000
3   1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225
4   1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225
5   2019-06-03 00:00:00.000000
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you only want the dates (without times), then the smallest date sans time component would be

```
pd.Timestamp.min.ceil('D')
# Timestamp('1677-09-22 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime(df['date'].fillna(pd.Timestamp.min.ceil('D')))

0   2014-10-01
1   1677-09-22
2   2015-09-30
3   1677-09-22
4   1677-09-22
5   2019-06-03
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```